# A single method for merging to images using a mask

Tags: python, opencv

The question is, how do I combine a foreground color, an empty background and a mask - black and white no gray, so that the mask applies the colour to the empty background in the area of the mask, and overlapping colour replaces without blend.

Some different approaches to part of this on SO and other places none that work as expected, such as .add, .addWeighted, bitwise_and, converting to rgba. Code that produces coloured horizontal lines on black

[image: black image]

```
bg = np.zeros_like(image)
fg = np.full_like(image, (250,50,150))
mask = np.zeros_like(image)
pts = np.array([[0,0],[0,50],[50,75],[125,0]], np.int32)
cv2.fillPoly(mask,[pts],(255,255,255))
comb_img = bg.copy()
comb_img[mask] = fg[mask]
```

Comment: And the question is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is in your last command. You want to copy the color from the foreground only where it is not zero in the mask. So it should be:

```
comb_img[mask!=0] = fg[mask!=0]
```

Here is an example:

Input:

[image]

import cv2
import numpy as np

```
# read image
image = cv2.imread('barn.jpg')

# color image with black for background
bg = np.zeros_like(image)

# color image with (250,50,150) as foreground
fg = np.full_like(image, (250,50,150))

# create mask by drawing a filled polygon from given points with white on black
mask = np.zeros_like(image)
pts = np.array([[0,0],[0,50],[50,75],[125,0]], np.int32)
cv2.fillPoly(mask,[pts],(255,255,255))

# do masking
comb_img = bg.copy()
comb_img[mask!=0] = fg[mask!=0]


cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.imshow('bg', bg)
cv2.imshow('fg', fg)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('result', comb_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# save results
cv2.imwrite('barn_color_masked.png', comb_img)
```

[image]